# Convert an OGF to an EGF

Tags: generating-functions

If I have an ordinary generating function (OGF) as a rational polynomial:

$$
Q(y) = \frac{f_1(y)}{g_1(y)}
$$

Which has a power series representation

$$
Q(y) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n y^n
$$

How can I compute the exponential generating function (EGF)
$$
Z(y) = \sum_{n \geq 0} b_n y^n / n!
$$
as a rational polynomial?
$$
Z(y) = \frac{f_2(y)}{g_2(y)}
$$

As an explicit solved example, consider the case where
$$ Q(y) = \frac{yv -1}{y(2+v) -1} $$
The intermediate terms are
$$ a_n  = 2 (v+2) ^ {n-1} $$
Giving as a final answer
$$ Z(y) = \frac{2 e^{(v+2)y}}{v+2} $$

... ideally, I like to be able to do this by going from one rational polynomial to another without computing $a_n$. We can assume that I can factor the polynomial $g_1(y)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is the Borel transform.  This is related to the inverse Laplace transform.  Specifically, $Z(s)$ is the inverse Laplace transform of $Q(1/t)/t$.

Comment: This doesn't seem give the right answer - looking it up on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=invlaplace%28+%28%281%2Ft%29*v-1%29%2F%28%281%2Ft%29*%282%2Bv%29-1%29%2Ft%2C+t%2C+s%29) gives an extra factor of $v/(v+2)$. It is however close, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your example wasn't quite right.  In the Maclaurin series of $Q(y) = (y v - 1)/(y (v+2) - 1)$, the coefficient of $y^k$ is $a_k = 2 (v+2)^{k-1}$ for $k \ge 1$, but is 1, not $2/(v+2)$, for $k=0$.  $Q(1/t)/t = (t-v)/(t(t-v-2)$, whose inverse Laplace transform is $Z(y) = (2 e^{(2+v)y}+v)/(v+2)$.  The Maclaurin series for this is indeed $1 + 2 y + \frac{2(v+2)}{2!} y^2 +  
\frac{2(v+2)^2}{3!} y^3 + \ldots$.